# Jetpack Compose - How can we call a @Composable function inside an onClick()

Tags: android-jetpack-compose

I know its not possible to call composable functions inside onClick.
@Composable invocations can only happen from the context of a @Composable function

Compose version - alpha06

But I'm stuck with the below requirement.
The requirement is,
Call a server api call inside an onClick.

```
LazyColumnFor(items = list) { reports ->
    Box(Modifier.clickable(
        onClick = {
            //API call
            val liveDataReportsDetails =
                viewModel.getReportDetails("xxxx")
            LiveDataComponentForReportsDetails(liveDataReportsDetails)


        }
    )) {

        ReportListItem(
            item = reports
        )
    }
}
```

Answer (score 51, accepted):

So you're right, composable functions cannot be called from within onClicks from either a button or a modifier. So you need to create a value like:

```
private val showDialog = mutableStateOf(false)
```

When set to true you want to invoke the composable code, like:

```
if(showDialog.value) {
    alert()
}
```

Alert being something like:

```
@Composable
fun alert() {
    AlertDialog(
        title = {
            Text(text = "Test")
        },
        text = {
            Text("Test")
        },
        onDismissRequest = {

        },
        buttons = {
            Button(onClick = { showDialog.value = false }) {
                Text("test")
            }
        }

    )
}
```

Now finish with changing the boolean where intended, like:

```
Box(Modifier.clickable(
    onClick = {
        showDialog.value = true
    }
))
```

I hope this explanation helps, of course the value doesn't have to be a boolean, but you get the concept :).

Comment: Thankyou @jobbert

Comment: @jobbert, to let it trigger if the value changes, where do you put the

if(showDialog.value) {
    alert()
} ?

Comment: btw is it best practice ?

Comment: @RohitJakhar there is not a universal rule for this, so really can't answer this question generic. It is best practice, if your code is clean. Depending on your architecture this can fit or not.

Comment: @soloturn     val showDialog = mutableStateOf(false)
        var ips = ""  object : MyIp.VolleyListner {
                                    override fun Onresponse(data: String) {
                                        ips = data; showDialog.value = true; }
                                }   if (showDialog.value) {
                            Greeting(name ="Volley"+ ips)
                        }  //dont worry showdialog is mutable value it will listen to change and hit .You can put the condition (if(show..) ) (eg:you can put anywhere the variable you can access)

Comment: How to pass value in dialog when I click on list item?

Comment: @NikolaC the dialog is a class-wide value in my example, hence the private statement.

Comment: Compose seems code complex like this handling.

Comment: I wish this was more clear in the official docs.

Comment: how above code is linked with each other? any github link would be helpful with complete code.

Comment: @parmesh please do make it! It would be very useful.

Comment: if you declare a variable in compose don't forget to wrap with remember function __private val showDialog = remember{mutableStateOf(false)}__

Comment: compose must have been created from 1.5 million stand up meetings. i hope the architect of it was duly fired. fits perfectly with the request permissions when you need them from the unobtainable activity. i won't even entertain the idea of learning this archaic ill thought out "thing". i truly feel sorry for people working with it daily sifting through 1000 lines of code and contexts to do what you can do with one line on other platforms.